# Vertical align on TD for email templates or newsletters

Tags: html-email, vertical-alignment

As you recommend on this site, I´m using nested tables for my email templates and newsletters. But, I´ve a problem with the vertical align.

Code…

```
…
<td align="center" height="30px" valign="middle" >
  <p style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16px;" align="center">
    Here is the text
  </p>
</td>
…
```

Now the explanation…

When I see it on my e-mail client (Thunderbird) I do not have problems.

When I see it on my outlook app on my android cellphone, I also do not have problems.

BUT, when I see it through the webmail of live.com, it respects the HEIGHT of the TD BUT NOT the valign attribute.

My question… Is there a universal way to align these contents vertically? If I was working on WEB, I know several, but, since all recommend TABLES for email templates, I´m stuck.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Resolved:

**Changing `<p>` for `<span>` and using valign** (because vertical-align:middle does not work in all the platforms) I see the same on the app, on the live webmail and on thunderbird.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use try to use vertical-align in style?
it worked for me.

```
<td align="center" height="30px" style="vertical-align:middle; " >
  <p style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16px;line-height:30px;" >
    Here is the text
  </p>
</td>
```

I changed styles.
I think p tag is not necessary here:

```
<td align="center" height="30px" style="vertical-align:middle;font-family: Verdana; font-size: 16px;line-height:30px; " >      
    Here is the text
</td>
```

Comment: Still not working. The same result: under webmail (live.com) appears like without alignment, or with top aligment. Anyway, thanks :D

Comment: @Tom play with p tag, try to add line-height, maybe might help

Comment: @Tom, I think p tag is not needed here, please try the changes I did

Answer (score 1):

Build 3 rows

```
<tr>
<td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Your content here</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Probably need to use some line-height and mso-line-height-rule:exactly etc in there to make it consistent, but should force a middle vertical align cross all clients.